# How to Copy and Paste cell with hyperlink based on drop down values

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, range, match

I am looking for a Excel VBA code to select the resulting Form address on Sheet 2 from the set of States on Sheet 1, but I need to copy the cell and paste it to retain the existing hyperlink attached to Form.

The only common data is the States.

I used INDEX MATCH but it only gets the word "Link" without the hyperlink itself.

I couldn't actually Select the cell, then copy and paste it.

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

I tried but don't have any idea how. As long when I choose what's selected on Sheet2 State (e.g Sheet2 Cell D2 - Alabama), the corresponding Form Link (e.g Sheet1 Cell B3 - Link) will be selected and copied through the Macro.

```
Sub test2()
Dim link As Range


Set link = Range("INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2State,Sheet1State,0),0)))")
Set s1 = Range("D5")

link.Copy
s1.PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

Comment: How do I change the Title?

Comment: Simply edit your post. Title has an own field at the top

Comment: Please provide your attempt so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Apologies, I'm still a beginner in using VBA. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Done editing, I hope you could help me with this.